# Change FFT frequency domain values range

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform

So, I`m currently working on program for computing spectrogram in real-time, using signal from a microphone. And now I want to add "scaling" feature, that allows to look at the spectrum more closely without losing frequency resolution (example was created using simple DFT) :

[image: Frequency scaling example]

This feature could be easily done using DFT algorithm ($DFT(freq) = \sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1}samples(n)*e^{-i*\frac{2\pi n}{N} * freq * scalingFactor}$), which also takes a lot of time to compute. 
And, to increase performance of the program I`m using FFT algorithm. So the question is : How to implement the same feature in the FFT **without severe loss of performance**? Increasing number of samples for computing transform ($N$) doesn't help, because it decreases time domain resolution. I've also considered using the trick from DFT example : $FFT(freq) = fft_{even}(freq) + e^{-i*\frac{2\pi}{N}*freq*scalingFactor}*fft_{odd}(freq)$, what also didn't help.
**Edit:** answers to the question at [FFT for a specific frequency range.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9251/fft-for-a-specific-frequency-range) actually provide methods to change FFT frequency domain values range, but (if I'm not mistaken) they require to compute Fourier transform two or more times (FFT and IFFT for applying filters) what increases computing time. So is there better way to  solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FFT for a specific frequency range.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9251/fft-for-a-specific-frequency-range)

Comment: This actually provides the way to solve my problem. But all suggested methods (if I'm not mistaken) require computing Fourier transform two or more times (FFT and IFFT for applying filters), what significantly increases computing time and isn't very good for the real-time algorithm. I think I will change the question to highlight this aspect. But if there is no another way to change the range, it would be better to close the question.